# Error "Unable to complete HTTP request" (code 141) with Parse Cloud Code

Tags: parsing, twilio, parse-cloud-code

we use Twilio (SMS sending platform) to send SMS via Parse Cloud Code.
We create the following js method to perform that :

```
var client = require('twilio')(CONSTANTS.SMS_TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID, CONSTANTS.SMS_TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN);

function sendSMS(from, to, message, success, error) {
  
  console.log("from:" + from + " to:" + to + " message:" +message);

  client.sendSms({
    to:to,
    from: from,
    body: message
  }, function(err, responseData) {
    if (err) {
      error(err, responseData);
    } else {
      success(err, responseData);
    }
  });
}
```

This code work perfectly until this now. During this night, we received always the following error in Parse logs console :

### {"status":0,"message":"Unable to complete HTTP request"}

On device, the error return by Parse contain code error 141 :

### {"status":0,"message":"Unable to complete HTTP request"} (Code: 141, Version: 1.12.0)

I try to send SMS directly from Twilio Website and it work perfectly. Do think Parse have an issue with HTTP request send from Cloud Code?

Regards

Comment: There is currently a known issue happening between Parse and Twilio.  You can watch this Github issue for updates: https://github.com/twilio/twilio-node/issues/152.  The issue also has work-around in the thread.

Comment: Looks like Parse have also opened an issue on their end as well: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1696266953962575/

Comment: Running into this with my app as well - using programmable SMSes from Parse cloud code using the twilio module. Code did not change - this started happening a few hours ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio Support here.

We have a temporary alternate endpoint in place that you can use: `api.twilio.com:8443`

Example:

```
Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
    method: "POST",
    url: "https://{your AccountSID}:{your AuthToken}@api.twilio.com:8443/2010-04-01/Accounts/{your AccountSID}/Messages.json",
    body: {
        To: "",
        From: "",
        Body: ""
    }
}).then(
    function(httpResponse) {
        console.log(httpResponse.text); // SUCCESS
    },
    function(httpResponse) {
        console.log(httpResponse.text); // ERROR
    }
);
}
```

Comment: Following up on this, Parse has now reverted the change to their certificates which should resolve the issue.  This work-around should no longer be required.